# Java file input Standard Deviation not calculating

Tags: java, file, io

I am having trouble with a file input program that is supposed to find the std dev of all the numbers on a file explicitly. However, the program is not importing the numbers and is returning 0 for the std dev and all variables associated with it.

Code:
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class File_io_practice {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    double avg;
    double median;
    double stdDev;
    double stdDevSum = 0.0;
    double stdDevLastSum = 0.0;
    double n = 0;
    double n1 = 0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    double lastSum = 0.0;
    double temp;
    int i;
    int j;

    File file = new File("File.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    for(i = 0; inputFile.hasNext(); i++){

        n = inputFile.nextDouble();

        sum = lastSum + n;
        lastSum = sum;

    }

    avg = lastSum / i;

    for(j = 0; inputFile.hasNext(); j++){
        n = inputFile.nextDouble();

        stdDevSum = ((n - avg) * (n - avg)) + stdDevLastSum;
        stdDevLastSum = stdDevSum;

    }

    temp = stdDevLastSum / (i - 1);
    stdDev = Math.sqrt(temp);
    System.out.print(stdDev);
}
```

}

Comment: In general: add print statements; or learn how to use a debugger. Will enable you to resolve such issues yourselves pretty fast ..

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you are checking `inputFile.hasNext()`, which you already know to be false, because it's the guard condition for your first for loop.

If you want to do it in two separate loops, you will need to close and reopen the file.

However, you can calculate standard deviation in a single for loop, which is desirable because it avoids doing the same IO twice. It is straightforward to derive the method by expanding the `(n - avg)^2` expression and rearranging the summations, or you can look in a search engine of your choice for "standard deviation single pass".

Comment: How would i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close and repoen the file. This is because when you do .nextDouble() it removes it from the buffer and you lose that value.

So do

```
 inputFile.close();
 inputFile = null;
 inputFile = new new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: 1) There is no need to assign a null value first. 2) It is better to use try-with-resources, so that the file is always closed, even if an exception occurs. 3) It is better *not* to need to close and open the file again :)